# How to not initialize the def init every time

Tags: python

this code is by tech with tim but i am trying to tweak it, i am trying to make the rotation velocity vary everytime.

```
import pygame
import time
import math
from utility import scale_image, blit_rotate_center
rotation_speed=2
Joystickx=0
GRASS = scale_image(pygame.image.load("Sprites/grass.png"),2.5)
TRACK = scale_image(pygame.image.load("Sprites/track.png"),0.7)
TRACK_BORDER = scale_image(pygame.image.load("Sprites/track-border.png"),0.7)
Car = scale_image(pygame.image.load("Sprites/F1.xcf"),0.1)
FINISH=pygame.image.load("Sprites/finish.png")
WIDTH, HEIGHT= TRACK.get_width(), TRACK.get_height()
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("F1")

FPS = 60



class AbstractCar:

    def __init__(self,max_vel,rotation_vel):
        self.img=self.IMG
        self.max_vel=max_vel
        self.vel = 0
        self.rotation_vel = rotation_vel
        self.angle = 90
        self.x, self.y = self.START_POS

    def rotate(self, left=False, right=False):
        if left:
            self.angle += self.rotation_vel
            print(self.angle)
        elif right:
            self.angle -= self.rotation_vel
            print(self.angle)

    def draw(self):
        blit_rotate_center(WIN, self.img,(self.x, self.y), self.angle)

class PlayerCar(AbstractCar):
    IMG = Car
    START_POS = (180,200)


def draw(win,images, player_car):
    for img, pos in images:
        win.blit(img,pos)

    player_car.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

run=True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
images = [(GRASS, (0,0)),(TRACK,(0,0))]

def rotate():
    global rotation_speed
    global Joystickx
    rotation_speed+=2*Joystickx
    rotation_speed*=0.9

while run:


    clock.tick(FPS)
    rotate()
    player_car = PlayerCar(4, rotation_speed)
    draw(WIN, images, player_car)





    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            break
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        player_car.rotate(left=True)
        Joystickx=-1
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player_car.rotate(right=True)
        Joystickx=1
    else:
        Joystickx=0


pygame.quit()
```

however, every time the class is ran, the code will set self.angle to 90, i do not want that to happen, what can i do to not let the def **init** run as that will set the self.angle to 94 instead remembering the last self.angle

Answer (score 0):

This is OOP (Object Oriented Programming) thing. I really suggest you to look it up, it's not an easy topic at first, but it's also not that hard to understand everything in it, it's just the first time is hard.

So, the `__init__` is the constructor of your `AbstractCar` class. This will always run when you make a new object from this class.

The simple way to fix this is to place the line where you define your car a bit above, outside the `while loop` and to keep the `rotation_vel` updated, we make a new method in the `AbstractCar` class and call it instead:

```
class AbstractCar:

    def set_rotation_vel(self, new_rotation_vel):
        self.rotation_vel = new_rotation_vel

[...]

player_car = PlayerCar(4, rotation_speed)
while run:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    rotate()
    player_car.set_rotation_vel(rotation_speed)
    draw(WIN, images, player_car)
```

Comment: but then the rotation speed will not vary as it will only be what at the start

Comment: I extend my answer with a solution for that, just a moment.

Comment: Extended solution.